# Capture assertion message in Pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to capture the return value of a PyTest. I am running these tests programmatically, and I want to return relevant information when the test fails.

I thought I could perhaps return the value of kernel as follows such that I can print that information later when listing failed tests:

```
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    kernel = os.system("uname -r")
    assert eval(test_input) == expected, kernel
```

This doens't work. When I am later looping through the `TestReport`s which are generated, there is no way to access any return information. The only information available in the `TestReport` is the name of the test and a `True`/`False`.

For example one of the test reports looks as follows:

```
<TestReport 'test_simulation.py::test_host_has_correct_kernel_version[simulation-host]' when='call' outcome='failed'>
```

Is there a way to return a value after the assert fails, back to the `TestReport`? I have tried doing this with PyTest plugins but have been unsuccessful.

Here is the code I am using to run the tests programmatically. You can see where I am trying to access the return value.

```
import pytest
from util import bcolors

class Plugin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.passed_tests = set()
        self.skipped_tests = set()
        self.failed_tests = set()
        self.unknown_tests = set()
    def pytest_runtest_logreport(self, report):
        print(report)
        if report.passed:
            self.passed_tests.add(report)
        elif report.skipped:
            self.skipped_tests.add(report)
        elif report.failed:
            self.failed_tests.add(report)
        else:
            self.unknown_tests.add(report)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plugin = Plugin()
    pytest.main(["-s", "-p", "no:terminal"], plugins=[plugin])
    for passed in plugin.passed_tests:
        result = passed.nodeid
        print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "[OK]\t" + bcolors.ENDC + result)
    for skipped in plugin.skipped_tests:
        result = skipped.nodeid
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "[SKIPPED]\t" + bcolors.ENDC + result)
    for failed in plugin.failed_tests:
        result = failed.nodeid
        print(bcolors.FAIL + "[FAIL]\t" + bcolors.ENDC + result)
    for unknown in plugin.unknown_tests:
        result = unknown.nodeid
        print(bcolors.FAIL + "[FAIL]\t" + bcolors.ENDC + result)
```

The goal is to be able to print out "extra context information" when printing the FAILED tests, so that there is information immediately available to help debug why the test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract failure details from the raised `AssertionError` in the custom [`pytest_exception_interact`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact) hookimpl. Example:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    # assertion message should be parsed here
    # because pytest rewrites assert statements in bytecode
    message = call.excinfo.value.args[0]
    lines = message.split()
    kernel = lines[0]
    report.sections.append((
        'Kernels reported in assert failures:',
        f'{report.nodeid} reported {kernel}'
    ))
```

Running a test module

```
import subprocess

def test_bacon():
    assert True

def test_eggs():
    kernel = subprocess.run(
        ["uname", "-r"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True
    ).stdout
    assert 0 == 1, kernel
```

yields:

```
test_spam.py::test_bacon PASSED                                          [ 50%]
test_spam.py::test_eggs FAILED                                           [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_eggs ___________________________________

    def test_eggs():
        kernel = subprocess.run(
            ["uname", "-r"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True
        ).stdout
>       assert 0 == 1, kernel
E       AssertionError: 5.5.15-200.fc31.x86_64
E         
E       assert 0 == 1
E         +0
E         -1

test_spam.py:12: AssertionError
--------------------- Kernels reported in assert failures: ---------------------
test_spam.py::test_eggs reported 5.5.15-200.fc31.x86_64
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_spam.py::test_eggs - AssertionError: 5.5.15-200.fc31.x86_64
========================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.05s ==========================
```